# B-Tree Filesystems: B-Tree per file or per filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

For filesystems such as btrfs and others which use B-Tree data structure, do they implement a B-Tree per file or single B-Tree for the whole filesystem ? What goes as the key and the value into such B-Trees ?

Comment: How would you implement it by file when it would then have a single value per tree?

Comment: We can have (data_offset => disk_block_num) for a single file's B-Tree ?